# Cancel upload angular-evaporate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, evaporate.js

I am using angular-evaporate https://github.com/uqee/angular-evaporate for uploading files to Amazon Web Service(AWS).
I need to add a cancel button in it.There is a function already available in Evaporate.js.

```
_.cancel = function(id){

    l.d('cancel ', id);
    if (files[id]){
       files[id].stop();
       return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }
 };
```

But i don't know how to cal it on a button click.I am new in angulare js,Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be done in latest master branch ([added 13 May](https://github.com/uqee/angular-evaporate/commit/6244f47f71b8973726c5043f11521cb638ab0c32#diff-fb01704089b53bd96a1a35d67ec34cdb)), but not in 1.4.3. To install master, run

```
bower uninstall angular-evaporate
bower install angular-evaporate#master
```

You could fork stable version or change angular-evaporate.js part with `eva._.add({` and change it to
`file.id = eva._.add({`
and once adding is complete, proxy evaporate.js method

```
      file.cancel = function(){
        eva._.cancel(file.id);
      };
```